# how can i send the values which are already inserted in sqlite DB to the MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have make an android app which is getting latitude and longitude from gps.Right now i have inserted them to the sqlite DB.but i want to pass those to values to the Mysql database which is created locally.

Here is my **main activity**

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting latlongs
                   Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                   db.addvalues(new LatLong("latvalue", "longvalue"));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });

}
 }
```

This is my **DataBaseHandler class**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gps";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "location";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String KEY_LONG = "long";

     public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LAT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LONG + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new values
    void addvalues(LatLong value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LAT, value.get_lat()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_LONG,  value.get_long()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


}
```

Comment: Retrieve the values and send using http connecition if it is located in cloud

Comment: @kiran kumar i am pretty new to android.can u give some suggestionsd by looking at above code segments?

Comment: try goggling how to retrieve values from database and how to send parameters to mysql

Comment: Where is this `Mysql database` is located?

Comment: @Madukar Hebbar It is created in localhost